# Numerical approximation of function of high dimensional vector

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, approximation, jacobian

I have a function which has as an input a vector of $\mathbb{R}^{18}$. The output of this function is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. How can I numerically approximate the differentiation of the function? I know how to do it if the function just delivers a single value, but not for two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have got a function $f$ s.t.

$$
f \, : \, \mathbb{R}^{18} \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}^2 
$$

When you derivate $f$, you obtain the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) that for $f$ it is a matrix $2 \times 18$ where the general entry is:
$$
\mathbf{J}_{i,j} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}
$$

For a numerical approximation of the Jacobian, i.e the approximation of   first order derivates, we can use the [finite difference method](http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~kuzmin/cfdintro/lecture4.pdf).

At this [link](http://www.maths.lth.se/na/courses/FMN081/FMN081-06/lecture7.pdf) at slide 3.7 there is a matlab code which use the function [jacobian](https://it.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/jacobian.html).

At this [link](https://books.google.it/books?id=9SG1r8EJawIC&pg=PT166&lpg=PT166&dq=jacobian+approximation+python&source=bl&ots=q5pCf2e2Fj&sig=LVMBIsi3TV6J6ea6N771X93pQ8Y&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifv8-BxtDQAhUEbhQKHSgIBp8Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=jacobian%20approximation%20python&f=false), from [1], at pag 157 see the *jacobian* function in python.

---

[1] Kiusalaas, Jaan. *Numerical methods in engineering with Python 3*. Cambridge university press, 2013.